# ngx-charts how to set the y-axis ticks width

Tags: ngx-charts

I'm currently using the ngx-charts library to display some data.

One UX problem I found is, due to the length of the y-axis ticks change(f.e 1000 and 100000), the chart will flick before the redraw.

I'm wondering if there is a way to set the width of the ticks?

I've tried to add space to the ticks (`&nbsp;`), but it will display as `&nbsp;1000`on the chart.

Anyone knows how to solve it?

UPDATE:
Click on the change button to see the flickering on y-axis.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-charts-flickering-problem?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Show your code to us

Comment: @A.Sakkeer here is a demo app I just made, https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-charts-flickering-problem?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: You can't stop the flickering. Because, flickering will happen depending on your data characters length (Ex: 1 and 100000).  Only the way to solve the problem is show hide concept using *ngIf. I am not sure this show hide is not a good solution, But if you want you can use. And That flickering issue is not a error, it's a chart behavior.

Comment: @A.Sakkeer is it possible to add empty spaces to the ticks?